# Simple function won't run, beginner coder at work

Tags: python-3.x, function

I'm learning Python and it's early days for me. The following small bit of code won't run, the error message is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'logdata' is not defined
```

The file is called "logdata.py". The faulty(?) code is;

```
def logthis(addme): 
   f=open("log.txt", "a+")
   f.write(addme)
   f.close()

logthis('teststring')
```

If there is a better place for a basic question like this please let me know, I'm sure i'll have plenty more to come as i learn Python, thanks!

Comment: maybe you want to show whats the first line of that file? Since the issue is in line 1

Comment: How are you running the code?  I notice that `logdata` doesn't show up anywhere in your file, but is in your error.

Comment: the entire file is shown. nothing is missing.

Comment: code is executed in cmd line, the mention of logdata is confusing to me too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you have some extra lines of code in beginning of file which uses undefined identifier (variable, function etc.) with name `logdata`. Something like this.

```py
>>> def f():
...     print(logdata)
... 
>>> f()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in f
NameError: name 'logdata' is not defined
>>>
```

If so, just define/initialize that. Finally, your code will work fine then as I have already tested it as follows.

```py
>>> def logthis(addme): 
...    f = open("log.txt", "a+")
...    f.write(addme)
...    f.close()
... 
>>> logthis('teststring')
>>> 
>>> # Read the newly created file content
...
>>> f = open("log.txt", "r")
>>> f.read()
'teststring'
>>>
```

Comment: comment by hygull helped me solve it. if hygull could run it, it occured to me something must be wrong in my environment. i had been running my cmd line from inside my python code folder , i dont know why but opening a new cmd line then manually setting the current folder to the python folder meant everything behaved as expected. thank you!